# P-type MOSFET is not turning off

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, pwm, buck, mosfet-driver

I am designing a buck converter as class assignment as shown in figure. I have calculated all the value of inductor and capacitor. I am applying PWM to the input of MAX627 MOSFET driver through PIC18f2420 Microcontroller. The PWM is perfect sqaure wave with 100Khz frequency and around 5Vpeak amplitude. The MOSFET is IRF9520 P-type. I am getting the same output voltage as input voltage i.e 10V. THe problem is that MOSFET is not turning off. I am not exactly sure why...?

MAX627 Mosfet driver datasheet: http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX626-TSC428.pdf

MOSFET datasheet: http://www.vishay.com/docs/91074/91074.pdf

[image]

That is [**This imgur image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPx6T.jpg)

Comment: You need to correct your diagram to show a P type MOSFET and the connection you are really using. People may not read through the comments to find what you are really doing and you waste their time AND you do not get the answers they could give you if your question is not correct. | **IF** you are doing what you say then it will work **SO** you must be doing something wrong. If you correct what you are doing so it is the same as what you say then it will work if you have not damaged the FET or driver. Note source MUST be connected to V+.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I already have edited and corrected the diagram

Comment: The diagram is still wrong. If what you show is what you are doing then it explains why it does not work. If you read what WRB wrote and what I wrote, carefully in each case, and do it, it will probably work. Note again, as I said above and as WRB said - the SOURCE MUST connect to V+. You show drain connected to V+.

Comment: You MAY have done as I have shown above - but you say you have corrected the diagram, and the diagram is still wrong. As what you say and what you show are different, and it does not work, we must assume that you are doing as shown.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Errm I am not exactly sure why my edited diagram is not showing up for you guys. IT is connected in the same way as you have implemented it. Anyways, After connecting the same way u have shown, it is not working out.. the MOSFET is not turning off and I m getting exact same output as input.

Comment: The diagram that is "showing up" is the ONLY one on your page and the link there is to the one I have ALSO linked to as [**This imgur image**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JPx6T.jpg) - that is copied from the edit level text on your page. Look at the two diagrams carefully. Look at the direction of the INTERNAL FET diode shown connected between drain and source. Yours is backwards. Look at the gate symbol. Yours is backwards. Look at the arrow in the FET in the middle element on the gate side. Yours is backwards. The MOSFET source is the right hand lead of 3, leads down, writing towards you...

Comment: ... ON the PHYSICAL REAL WORLD FET does V+ from the power supply connect to this RIGHT HAND lead? Does the inductor connect to the MIDDLE terminal and/or the tab. IF NOT then your FET is BACKWARDS. If it does then the only diagram on your page that you have put there is WRONG.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Yes Sir, in physical real world, the mosfet is connected as u have explained. Right hand lead to supply positive and middle tab to the inductor.

Comment: OK. That is good. That is not what your diagram shows. The imgur image is what I see when I look at your page or use the direct link to the image. **BUT** if inductor goes to the middle lead that is correct (despite the diagram :-) ). ||SO: IF driver is putting 0V/10V PWM signal on gate then FET is dead (or it IS turning off :-) ). Try this: disconnect driver from FET gate. Connect FET gate to source = V+ = 10V. FET "must" turn off. If it does not FET is dead. If it does and driver puts a 0/10V signal at FET gate then it is Murphy's birthday :-).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon haha I am in lab at the moment, so I am doing as you say. I connected the FET gate to positive supply and it turns off at around 7V when I supply mosfet source with 10V

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Upon checking gate signal with Oscilloscope. I can see a 10.2Vpeak-peak square wave with 50% duty cycle. But, the MOSFET is not turning off, nor getting off... Is it that P-type MOSFET gate voltage needs to be lowered to turn it off?

Comment: P channel mosfet is off when Gate is at or near source voltage. Fet is on when gate is enough negative wrt source. For this fet you need about 56V drive or more to turn on well so fet is one when gate is <= 5V and off when gate is say 7V to 10v. | NBNBNB - if FET is turning OFF when you put 7V on gate but not when you put 1 0V/10V drive signal then summat aglae. | Connect say 1K resistor across output "catch" diode and remove inductor. What do you see across the resistor. | In original form - what do you see at various points. What is Vout and what value is load resistor?

Comment: Ah. 10k. Rather light. What is signal on gate like - nice and square and 0/10Vish.  Try 10 kHz drive for now. Inductor is large. Will be continuous conduction mode.

Comment: Diagram is still wrong :-)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon AH sorry for mess, Ptype mosfet was not working so I switched to ntype. AND yeh, finally it is working!

Comment: If an N type MOSFET works in the circuit shown then you are doing something totally different that you are showing. What is your REAL circuit?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Ntype mosfet works. I just changed the source and drain connections. Source is connected to inductor while drain is connected to supply.

Comment: Well .... whatever it is you are doing it isn't what your diagram shows - nor anything overly close. When you work out what you are really doing you should update or redraw the diagram.

Comment: The diagram is wrong and that and the text are misleading. Updated information is in the comments but not the question. The question should be updated and the diagram fixed or it will misled others. What you suggest with an NFET working and a PFET not indicates that things are not connected as you say. Probably the gate signal generator is sitting on top of V+ - which would explain most things.

Answer (score 2):

It's really  pretty straightforward. You've swapped the drain and source. As a result, you're getting current flow through the MOSFET body diode. For a p-type, the source should be connected to the more positive side of the MOSFET. Note that, on the data sheet, figure 10a (which you probably used as your guide) uses a negative voltage source - that is, the top of the schematic is the negative lead, rather than the positive lead as is usually shown in schematics.

Comment: Sorry, it was drawing error. I made ntype mosfet instead of ptype mosfet. I have corrected it now. In real life, i have connected ptype mosfet as you have said.

Comment: Still not correct. You still have the source on the right.

Comment: I am not sure why it is not showing up on ur screen. Anyways, my actual circuit is as u have told and as updated above by Rusell. Still, its not working out, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Connect pull-up resistor between gate and drain. You may connect 10k ohm